# Como retirar banner lateral fixo do footer

Tags: html, css, css3

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer com que o banner lateral pare antes de ficar por cima do footer conforme imagem abaixo, porem não consegui encontrar um meio que faça essa  ficar fixada na lateral da pagina e não fique por cima do footer da pagina.
[image: erro banner lateral - sidebar]

Codigo HTML:

```
<section class="noticia">

    <header>
        <h1>titulo noticia</h1>
    </header>

    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc non mauris mi. Sed a ullamcorper massa. Nulla sed efficitur odio, id porttitor mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut porttitor tincidunt magna, at molestie libero pretium a. Duis placerat pretium fermentum. Mauris facilisis, erat ac accumsan ultrices, nunc mauris blandit risus, at venenatis ipsum ipsum ut lectus. In ac rhoncus felis. Suspendisse facilisis convallis condimentum. Donec volutpat lorem nec neque commodo luctus. Donec tempor facilisis varius.</p>
    </article>
    <div class="fixo">
        <img src="images/imagem300x250.png"/>
    </div>
</section>
```

Código CSS:

```
.fixo {
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    top: 380px;
    left: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: ⚠️ Se seu footer for responsivo, a resposta do Hugocss não vai funcionar.

Comment: Por isso temos os @media... Eles estão ai justamente para corrigir o CSS na responsividade... Mas acredito que uma resposta em js eh bem vinda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim, nessa `div` que fica fixa vc coloca um top de 100% - a altura dela mesmo e a altura do `footer`. Seria algo como `top: calc(100% - (altura div fixa + altura do footer) )`. Para isso vc usa um função de `calc()` do css deixei isso comentado no código.

O legal dessa técnica é que não importa a altura da tela essa `div` fixa nunca vai encobrir o `footer`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.fixo {
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    /* 200 é 100px da altura do footer e 100px da própria div fixa */
    top: calc(100% - 200px); 
    left: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
article {        
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: silver;
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="noticia">
    <header>
        <h1>titulo noticia</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis animi quo nulla! Autem magnam doloremque animi, dolorem hic impedit laboriosam reprehenderit debitis perferendis deleniti dignissimos nostrum, et, culpa sequi ducimus.
    </article>

    <div class="fixo">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
    </div>
    
</section>

<footer>
    footer
</footer>
```

Comment: verdade, havia me esquecido!! valeu

Comment: @GabrielHenrique legal jovem, qq dúvida estamos ai. []´s

Comment: Se o footer for responsivo sua sugestão vai bixar :D.. só resolveria com JS

Comment: @Sam só ajustar o CSS nos breacking points dos media queries. Isso se o footer nunca for maior que 100% da altura da tela, o que eu acho que vai ser muito pouco provável... Os `@media` estão ai justamente para isso, corrigir o CSS na responsividade. Mas se quiser contribuir com uma resposta em JS a comunidade agradece 